# Freebase MQL Query - Not Returning Results

Tags: freebase, mql

I am trying a couple of very simple queries to retrieve members of a political party, specifically the UK Labour Party, from Freebase. I am unable to get them to return any results, and would welcome any thoughts as to why this is:

*Query 1:*

```
[{
    "id": "/m/01c9x",
    "name": null,
    "/government/political_party/politicians_in_this_party": []
}]
```

*Query 2:*

```
[{
  "type": "/government/politician",
  "mid": null,
  "name": null,
  "/government/politician/party": {
      "mid": "/m/01c9x"
  }
}]
```

I am attempting to run them at the following site: http://www.freebase.com/query

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The connection to the party is date mediated, so you need to go one hop further out:

```
[{
  "type": "/government/politician",
  "mid": null,
  "name": null,
  "party": [{
    "party": {
      "id": "/m/01c9x"
    }
  }]
}]
```

If you want want to constrain by membership in the party on certain dates, you can use the `from` and `to` properties on the mediator node.